# Android - How to develop to bluegiga device?

Tags: android, sdk, bluetooth

I would like to send data to an android mobile device via a bluegiga module.

My question is, what SDK I need for that, and how can I get it?

What I found is Bluegiga SDK, but there's not a lot of information about it.

Answer (score 1):

BlueGiga modules may come with SSP support. That is, Serial Port Profile. If so, you should be able to connect to the module using RS232 type physical interface and use SPP profile from the android device.

Module documentation should have information about security and pairing e.g. default pin number when Android connects to the module and if there is a pin/button to be initiate connection and pairing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to get the knowledge of how BLE works. Its different than classic Bluetooth that BLE (generally) is preferred to communicate by means of service/s (with characterstic/s bundled up into them), be them Standard or Custom. Depending upon your area of application you can select one of the standard services implementation.
For more info on services, check [Bluetooth Developer Portal](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BLE.aspx).

About development at BlueGiga device, you will have to device upon which way you would want to proceed: *BGAPI* or *BGScript*. *BGAPI* is incorporated into a readily portable (C-programming based) library: *bglib* that you can easily port in your main firmware project.

Then you will have to take one of the standard services to get started with and dump the `.hex` file into the BLE module (either directly or if you have the Eval kit). The `.hex` file is generated from a *BGProject* that contains few configuration files like `gatt.xml`, `hardware.xml` and few others which are present in the demo projects that you can receive from BlueGiga when you download the SDK and other tools. To dump the `.hex` into the module, you'll need to get a [TI-made CC Debugger](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-debugger).

Understand the [GATT implementation](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx) and [GAP implementation](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile).

Tool that you'll require for setting up the BLE device is: *BLEUpdate*. It runs on windows platform flawlessly (Window XP service pack 2 onwards). There are plenty of documents and user guides available on [BlueGiga product Support Page](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/support/) to get hand on knowledge of how this should be used.

To put it in a simple way:

- To start with, pick a standard service probably from a demo project. Dump the `.hex` file into the BLE module / Eval kit.
- Share the **UUIDs** from `gatt.xml` with the android application code.
- Do necessary implementation at android app in order to discover and connect with the BLE device.